# Why is my left join not working showing zeros?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get authors with zeros within the date but I only get those that sold.

```
SELECT v.author_name, COUNT(*)
FROM bookssold s
LEFT JOIN authors v ON s.author_id = v.author_id
WHERE s.price = 19
AND DATE(s.purchase_date) BETWEEN '2009-01-20' AND DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY s.author_id
```

this should be working according to other posts.

v is authors table with id and name

s is books sold with author id, price, and purchase date

Comment: *I am trying to get authors with zeros within the date* What does that mean?

Comment: Please post your schema too.

Comment: Nice aliasing from `ss` to `s`. That will save time :)

Comment: lol none are my table names. had to leave something to be readable. the table vd has all authors. i want authors that have not sold any books with zeros

Comment: @Dev-Ria, what do you mean sold any books with zeros?  What field are you referring to?  According to your question you only have three fields in the `books sold` table.  I don't understand the reasoning for looking for 0s in `id`, `price`, or `purchase date`.

Comment: ok so I need to show author_name and counts of how many books sold for 19. if the author did not sell or have any books for $19 i want to show a zero.

Comment: it should be clear now what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but here goes.

If `ss` is a record of a sale and `vd` is the author name/id, and you want a list containing each author, regardless of whether he has a sale, with sales if any, then you have the tables switched on your `LEFT JOIN`. Instead you want

```
...
FROM vd
LEFT JOIN ss ON ss.id = vd.id
...
```

Alternatively you could keep them in the order you have and use a `RIGHT JOIN` but I think `LEFT` makes more sense.

If you want the result to show zeroes instead of `NULL`, you have to use a `CASE` or something, but that's a separate question.

I would suggest trying the following:

```
SELECT v.author_name, COUNT(*)
FROM authors v
LEFT JOIN bookssold s 
    ON s.author_id = v.author_id
    AND s.price = 19
    AND DATE(s.purchase_date) BETWEEN '2009-01-20' AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY v.author_id;
```

Comment: thats what I am trying to do but even if I switch the tables I still get only authors that sold books. I dont get any zeros. There are 50 authors and only 20 solds books. I only get 20 back. I'm still missing the other 30.

Comment: @Dev-Ria When you reverse the JOIN order, did you move the WHERE filter to the JOIN instead of the where?  If you are using `LEFT JOIN bookssold` then after the `ON` condition you will add `AND s.price = 19 AND DATE(s.purchase_date) BETWEEN '2009-01-20' AND DATE(NOW())` and remove the WHERE.

Comment: Then changing the select to `COUNT(s.purchase_date)` or something should give you the number sold, or `0` if none (I think; no way for me to test right now).

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I edited your answer with a sample query that I think should work.

Comment: @Dev-Ria see the edit to this answer, having the filters in a WHERE clause are causing your query to behave similar to an INNER JOIN which you don't want.

Comment: yea I think the where clause is the issue. I used the query above but now I get all authors with some zeros except the counts are not right. they are much lower than my original query that gave no zeros.

Comment: wait! it does work. When i run author on a separate query on the bookssold table matching the where, I get the same counts as the query from "iamnotmaynard."